# Key (user_id)=(7) is not present in table "auth_user"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

i am using djoser's create token end point to login user but i am getting following error. 
[image]

I have tried google search but could not find any useful answer.

**UPDATE**
I have customized user model to add an extra field while registering user.
here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from custom_user.models import AbstractEmailUser


class UserProfile(AbstractEmailUser):
    account_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and this is my serializer.py

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    advertisements = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='advertisement-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'advertisements', 'name', 'account_address', 'password')
```

and urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls')),
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken'))
]
```

Comment: Show us your code please, otherwise it is very hard to help you

Comment: @Dalvtor chack update in question

Comment: Also you don't need to post a screenshot of the error. If you use `python manage.py runserver` you can just copy the essential part of the error traceback and paste it here.